# Spacing between numbers in flipcounter plugin animation - jquery

Tags: jquery

We want to implement the flipping of digits. I am using the **Flipcount** plugin in which we have to give the full number image in `.png` format. But my problem is that we want a gap between the numbers, as shown in the fig. below:

[image]

I'm using **FlipCounter 1.2** plugin. My code and config is:

```
$(".total_box").flipCounter({
        number:10032463, // the initial number the counter should display, overrides the hidden field
        numIntegralDigits:1, // number of places left of the decimal point to maintain
        numFractionalDigits:0, // number of places right of the decimal point to maintain
        digitClass:"counter-digit", // class of the counter digits
        counterFieldName:"counter-value", // name of the hidden field
        digitHeight:40, // the height of each digit in the flipCounter-medium.png sprite image
        digitWidth:30, // the width of each digit in the flipCounter-medium.png sprite image
        imagePath:"../layout/images/flipCounter-medium.png", // the path to the sprite image relative to your html document
        easing: true, // the easing function to apply to animations, you can override this with a jQuery.easing method
        duration:10, // duration of animations
        onAnimationStarted:false, // call back for animation upon starting
        onAnimationStopped:false, // call back for animation upon stopping
        onAnimationPaused:false, // call back for animation upon pausing
        onAnimationResumed:false // call back for animation upon resuming from pause
});
```

Currently I'm getting:

[image]

**How do add spaces between the numbers?**

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: just inspect and find the right element and override it by adding `padding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.counter-digit {margin: 0px 10px;}
```

or append `margin: 0px 10px;` to any current styling of `.counter-digit` if it's already present.

Comment: Thanks.it is working now. I was trying to give padding which didn't work :)